# Getting coordinates points of the path using Google Map on Iphone MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am using the MKMapView SDK.
I can get the coordinates of two points. but how do I get the path ,array of coordinate points generated by Google so, I can draw that path on the MKMapView?

Google is the one that calculated the shortest path between the 2 points. How I do that on the Iphone?

where and how to generate that route.kml file??

// Locate the path to the route.kml file in the application's bundle
    // and parse it with the KMLParser.
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"route" ofType:@"kml"];
    kml = [[KMLParser parseKMLAtPath:path] retain];

Comment: You want shortest path or the path that google draws in their map? There is webservice for the getting route point coordinates http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/.